# Angular pushing into blank String array

Tags: angular

I have a blank array declared,

```
ExcldMods: string[];
```

and I am trying to push new elements into it,

```
if (item.ExcldMods) {
        this.ExcldMods = [];
        for (let em of item.ExcldMods) {
          this.ExcldMods.push(em);
        }
}
```

But its not pushing into the array,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be the event which you're trying to execute this conditional compared to the event when you are writing to `console.log`.

A couple of other notes:

- Don't start variable names with an uppercase unless you're defining a class. Use `excldMods` instead.
- You are emptying `excldMods` before executing the `for` loop. If this is your intended case it's much simpler to just assign the array. `this.excldMods = item.excldMods`